# I have a large CSV (53Gs) and I need to process it in chunks in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiprocessing

I tried out the pool.map approach given in similar answers but I ended up with 8 files of 23G each which is worse.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool

#csv file name to be read in
in_csv = 'mycsv53G.csv'

#get the number of lines of the csv file to be read
number_lines = sum(1 for row in tqdm((open(in_csv, encoding = 'latin1')), desc = 'Reading number of lines....'))
print (number_lines)

#size of rows of data to write to the CSV,
#you can change the row size according to your need

rowsize = 11367260 #decided based on your CPU core count 

#start looping through data writing it to a new file for each set

def reading_csv(filename):
    for i in tqdm(range(1,number_lines,rowsize), desc = 'Reading CSVs...'):
      print ('in reading csv')
      df = pd.read_csv(in_csv, encoding='latin1',
        low_memory=False,
        header=None,
        nrows = rowsize,#number of rows to read at each loop
        skiprows = i)#skip rows that have been read

  #csv to write data to a new file with indexed name. input_1.csv etc.
  out_csv = './csvlist/input' + str(i) + '.csv'


  df.to_csv(out_csv,
        index=False,
        header=False,
        mode='a',#append data to csv file
        chunksize=rowsize)#size of data to append for each loop

def main():
    # get a list of file names
    files = os.listdir('./csvlist')
    file_list = [filename for filename in tqdm(files) if filename.split('.')[1]=='csv']

    # set up your pool
    with Pool(processes=8) as pool: # or whatever your hardware can support
        print ('in Pool')
        # have your pool map the file names to dataframes
        try:
            df_list = pool.map(reading_csv, file_list)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above approach took 4 hours to split the files in a concurrent fashion and then parsing every CSV will be even more.. not sure if multiprocessing helped or not!

Currently, I read the CSV file through this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
        for chunk in dd.read_csv(filename, chunksize = 10**5, encoding='latin-1', skiprows=1, header=None):
        #chunk processing
    final_df = final_df.append(agg, ignore_index=True)

final_df.to_csv('Final_Output/'+output_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

It takes close to 12 hours to process the large CSV at once.

What will the improvements here be?
Any suggestions?
I am willing to try out dask now.. but no other options left.

Comment: Depending on your data/needs, some of these might make a difference like shrinking `dtypes`, leaving out cols, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66672335/13138364

Comment: how many columns does the file have?

Comment: How many RAM you have? Split into smaller file size it's definitely a good idea. Use `split` in linux  or a compiled progarm (7-zip, or similar used for compression) in Windows . They can be very fast. Then process it in parallel .  It depends on how many processors you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read the csv file line by line and feed the lines into a queue from which the processes pick their tasks. This way, you don't have to split the file first.

See this example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53847284/4141279